# Get Files Inside a folder in Document directory in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsmutablearray, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

I am new to iPhone,

I made an app in which, i am downloading a book and storing it in a folder called `book1Folder` which is inside `Document directory`.

now i wants name of all books in my array, there are 2 books inside a `book1Folder` but when i  write this code it shows me array count is 3.

Here is my code snippet,

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSString *files;
    NSString *Dir=[self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
    Dir=[Dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"book1Folder"];

    NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:Dir];

    Downloadedepubs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    while(files = [direnum nextObject])
    {
        if([[files pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"epub"])
            NSLog(@"files=%@",files);
            [Downloadedepubs addObject:files];
    }
}
```

My log shows only name of 2 book, but when i loop through array it contains 3 objects.

```
[Downloadedepubs ObjectAtIndex:0]=.DS_Store;
[Downloadedepubs ObjectAtIndex:1]=abcd;
[Downloadedepubs ObjectAtIndex:2]=pqrs;
```

***What is that `.DS_Store` why it is coming ?***

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Comment: .DS_Store file is created by os. You can ignore it.

Comment: Why it is get added to my array even if i wrote `if([[files pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"epub"])` then only add book to my array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get your if block in curly brackets. It affects only first line after if.

Like below;

```
if([[files pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"epub"]) {
            NSLog(@"files=%@",files);
            [Downloadedepubs addObject:files];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.DS_Store is a hiden file in mac to store your files message in the Folder.you can delete it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  NSDirectoryEnumerator*    e = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:yourPathhere];

// Ignore any files except XYZ.epub
for (NSString*  file in e)
{
    if (NSOrderedSame == [[file pathExtension] caseInsensitiveCompare:@"epub"])
    {
           // Do something with file.epub
               [Downloadedepubs addObject:files];

    }
    else if ([[[e fileAttributes] fileType] isEqualToString:NSFileTypeDirectory])
    {
        // Ignore any subdirectories
        [e skipDescendents];
    }
}
```